# ActiveX control cannot be instantiated because the current thread is not in a single-threaded apartment

Tags: .net, winforms, multithreading

As the subject is self explainatory, I need help.

I'm writing a small tool that displays a splash screen when starting.
The splash screen is a Form. When there was only a Button control on it it was working fine.
But when I removed it and placed a WebBrowser control on it, it throws the above exception.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using WinForms? If so, try placing the [STAThread] attribute at the top of your class definition and see what happens:

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    [STAThread]
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

Comment: it says I can use this attribute only with Method definitions, not class declarations

Comment: My mistake. Its actually applied to the Main function of your application class

Comment: What if you are doing threading in your program, I had to switch as follows:         // must change this for threading to avoid error:
        // "waitall for multiple handles on an sta thread is not supported"  [MTAThread()] to work with this statement: ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(webSvc.ThreadPoolCallback, i);